# I keep getting a 400 error when i am using createAsyncThunk and axios

Tags: javascript, react-redux

Hi everyone i dont know if anyone can help on this but when using createAsyncThunk and Axios whenever i try to POST something I get a 400 error. And I know that means it is a bad request but I dont know why I am getting it. And here my code

```
const API_URL =
  'https://us-central1-bookstore-api-e63c8.cloudfunctions.net/bookstoreApi/apps/sppWoQdq6XBTog313fKt/books';

export const defaultState = [];

export const getBooks = createAsyncThunk(GET_BOOKS, async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(API_URL);
  return response.data;
});

export const addBook = createAsyncThunk(ADD_BOOK, async (book) => {
  const response = await axios.post(API_URL, book);
  return response.data;
});

export const removeBook = createAsyncThunk(REMOVE_BOOK, async (book) => {
  const response = await axios.delete(`${API_URL}${book.id}`);
  return response.data;
});

export const bookSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'books',
  initialState: defaultState,
  extraReducers: (builders) => {
    builders.addCase(getBooks.fulfilled, (action) => action.payload);
  },
});

export default bookSlice.reducer;
```

I have tried everything i can to understand why I am getting this error differant api's differant code i dont know what the problem is

Comment: Try to add Content-Type: application/json headers? Sometimes server do not recognize json without that header

Comment: hey @AndreyBessonov how would that code look?

Comment: added example as full comment

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force json header:

```
axios.post(API_URL, book, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
```

Comment: hey @AndreyBessonov  it didnt work but i appreciate the help ! I am still getting a 400 error on the post and an Uncaught (in promise) from axios

Comment: Do you have any api documentation, maybe you need use auth header? Like {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`}